# Request for oauth_token for Twitter shows "Sorry this page doesn't exist" error

Tags: api, twitter, error-handling, twitter-oauth, oauth-1.0a

I am sending an API request to get my oauth_token through postman. This is my request:
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=oob

where the header is Content-Type:application/json and I am providing API key and secret under the Authorization Tab with OAuth 1.0.

On sending this get request, the request returns the error "Sorry, this page doesn't exist".

[Please check the image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyZYP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I used https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=oob and it resolved my issue. Twitter used to use "api.twitter.com"  call to authorize API request but they changed back to "twitter.com" which worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).